# Ogg Vorbis header specifications

Tags: oggvorbis

I am looking for specifications for the ogg vorbis header packet format. I have searched the Internet without much success. Where can I find one?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ogg#Page_structure describes what every single page in an ogg file looks like -- file metadata and stream data alike.
- http://xiph.org/vorbis/doc/Vorbis_I_spec.html actually describes the contents of a ogg vorbis file's metadata (header) pages. The three header packets are:

  - an Identification Header,
  - a Comment Header, and
  - a Setup Header.

The specification *requires* that all three of these headers be present.

Comment: after 12 years, is there any better resource you can recommend? I'm looking to find how the file header is constructed. All resources I found so far are very complex.

Answer (score 3):

A bitfield diagram of the Ogg Vorbis identification header is at http://wiki.xiph.org/OggVorbis.

Answer (score 1):

Hope this is what you're looking for:
http://xiph.org/vorbis/doc/v-comment.html

Comment: That page describes the "header packets that begin a Vorbis bitstream" but it does not describe the other headers nor does it say how the headers are laid out within the ogg container format.